# I want to connect my java web application with mysql database but getting error

Tags: mysql, jdbc, database-connection, classnotfoundexception

Driver Not Foundjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver

I want to make connection between my java web application and mysql database through XAMP. 
I also have added external jar file which is mysql-connector-java-6.0.2.jar but still i am getting this error.

I have done this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
        System.out.println("Driver has been found..");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Driver Not Found"+ex);
    }

    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/hms";
    String user="root";
    String password="";

    Connection con=null;

    try {
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Driver is successfully loaded.");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Something is not good.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect Java to a MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class names in Java are case-sensitive. You need to capitalize the "D" in "driver":

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
// Here ----------------------^
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write this because because java is **Case-Sensitive**

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver has been found..");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Driver Not Found"+ex);
    }

    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/hms";
    String user="root";
    String password="";

    Connection con=null;

    try {
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Driver is successfully loaded.");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Something is not good.");
    }
}
```